# Symfony 6.2 : Problem when try to register on extended class

Tags: symfony, symfony6

I have two classes: Eleve (means Student) and User.

The Eleve class extends the User class and I try to register with this Eleve class.

But Symfony give me this error:

[image: An exception occurred while executing a query: Column not found: Unknown column 't0.email' in 'where clause']

And the query that Symfony execute is :

```
SELECT t1.id AS id_2, t1.email AS email_3, t1.roles AS roles_4, t1.password AS password_5, t1.is_verified AS is_verified_6, t1.date_naissance AS date_naissance_7, t1.adresse AS adresse_8, t1.genre AS genre_9, t1.responsable_legal_id AS responsable_legal_id_10 FROM eleve t1 WHERE t0.email = 'a@aaaa.fr' LIMIT 2;
```

I don't know if this is the reel problem but here the query try to access the email property on the t0 table but only the t1 table is refered.

Comment: Please share your QueryBuilder code here. Also prefer not to share images, but message text itself

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.